# Domain controller and user based on email VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to resolve domain controller name and user(dc\user) using email address.

I have below code(borrowed) but it only solves user name for default domain. Any suggestions much appreciated.

```
Function Get_LDAP_User_Properties(strObjectType, strSearchField, strObjectToGet, strCommaDelimProps)

    If InStr(strObjectToGet, "\") > 0 Then
        arrGroupBits = Split(strObjectToGet, "\")
        strDC = arrGroupBits(0)
        strDNSDomain = strDC & "/" & "DC=" & Replace(Mid(strDC, InStr(strDC, ".") + 1), ".", ",DC=")
        strObjectToGet = arrGroupBits(1)
    Else
        ' Otherwise we just connect to the default domain
        Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
        strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    End If

    strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
    ' Setup ADO objects.
    Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set ADOConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ADOConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    ADOConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    adoCommand.ActiveConnection = ADOConnection


    ' Filter on user objects.
    'strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    strFilter = "(&(objectClass=" & strObjectType & ")(" & strSearchField & "=" & strObjectToGet & "))"

    ' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
    strAttributes = strCommaDelimProps
    arrProperties = Split(strCommaDelimProps, ",")

    ' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
    strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    ' Define the maximum records to return
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    ' Run the query.


End Function
```

Thanks in advance
Michal

Answer (score 1):

This should be the code you need to get what you want.

It takes an email address and returns the attributes listed in `strAttributes` of the requested user.

**Example:**

Input: `LdapUserByMailAddress("ad.user@ad.example.com")`
Output: `sn: Doe; givenName: John; mail: ad.user@ad.example.com;`
Value of `strBaseDn`: `<LDAP://dc=ad,dc=example,dc=com>`

```
Public Function LdapUserByMailAddress(strMailAddress As String) As String
    Dim arrMailParts() As String
    Dim strUsername As String
    Dim strDomain As String
    Dim strBaseDn As String
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strAttributes As String
    Dim arrAttributes() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    strAttributes = "mail,sn,givenName"
    arrAttributes = Split(strAttributes, ",")

    arrMailParts = Split(strMailAddress, "@")

    If 1 <> UBound(arrMailParts) Then
        LdapUserByMailAddress = "Not a valid email address"
        Exit Function
    End If

    strUsername = arrMailParts(0)
    strDomain = arrMailParts(1)

    strBaseDn = "<LDAP://dc=" & Replace(strDomain, ".", ",dc=") & ">"

    strFilter = "(sAMAccountName=" & strUsername & ")"

    ' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
    strQuery = strBaseDn & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

    Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set ADOConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ADOConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    ADOConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    adoCommand.ActiveConnection = ADOConnection
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    Set resultSet = adoCommand.Execute
    LdapUserByMailAddress = ""
    For i = 0 To resultSet.Fields.Count - 1
        LdapUserByMailAddress = LdapUserByMailAddress & resultSet.Fields(i).Name & ": "

        If resultSet.Fields(i).Type = adVariant And Not (IsNull(resultSet.Fields(i).Value)) Then
            ' For Multi Value attribute.
            LdapUserByMailAddress = LdapUserByMailAddress & "[MultiValue]"
            For j = LBound(resultSet.Fields(i).Value) To UBound(resultSet.Fields(i).Value)
                LdapUserByMailAddress = LdapUserByMailAddress & resultSet.Fields(i).Value(j) & " # "
            Next j
        Else
            ' For Single Value attribute.
             LdapUserByMailAddress = LdapUserByMailAddress & resultSet.Fields(i).Value
        End If

        LdapUserByMailAddress = LdapUserByMailAddress & ";"
    Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate about the given email addresses and add examples about the parameters `strObjectType, strSearchField, strObjectToGet and strCommaDelimProps` when calling the function `Get_LDAP_User_Properties()`.

What is the expected result?

What is the actual result?

*My interpretation of your question:*
Your input is an email address like `myuser@dc.example.com` and you want to get following result: `dc.example.com\myuser`

Is this correct?

In that case this could be the solution:

```
Public Function LdapUserByMailAddress(strMailAddress As String) As String
    Dim arrParts() As String

    arrParts = Split(strMailAddress, "@")

    If 1 <> UBound(arrParts) Then
        LdapUserByMailAddress = "Not a valid email address"
        Exit Function
    End If

    LdapUserByMailAddress = arrParts(1) & "\" & arrParts(0)

End Function
```

If you call this function in your worksheet with following code:
`=LdapUserByMailAddress("user@dc.example.com")`

you get this result: `dc.example.com\user`

Comment: Hello,Parameters as follow Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "userPrincipalName", strUser, "samAccountName") where strUser is an email. The end result would be xyz/userName our standardised emails are user.name@abc.com but they may live in different domains eg result may be xyz/userName abc/userName and so on as they live in different  domains. Daomain name should be sorted using LDAP query so 
objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE") 
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
should be replaced with lookup to domain but I cant find code for this
Thanks for reply Michal